# Not able to inspect one of the overlay which disappears in fraction of sec before page loads completely

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Once i reset the password through selenium script the confirmation overlay page just remains for 2 sec which i`s not captured by selenium to inspect. Please suggest   me how to capture/ignore that step and continue to next step?

Please find script pattern below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='resetPassword']//input[@class='aButton grnBtn ae-button']")).click();
      try
         {
           WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul//li[6][@id='logoutLink']//a"));
         }
      catch(TimeoutException toe)
      {
           WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5000);
          wait.until( ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ul//li[6][@id='logoutLink']//a")));
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul//li[6][@id='logoutLink']//a")).click();
                 }
          //System.out.println("Password reset successfully");
          Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//header[@id='mainHeader']/div/nav[contains(@class,'right no_print')]/ul/li[5]")).size() > 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

xpath is the slowest way to match an element , you could use By.id to give yourself a fighting chance.

your element looks like 'logoutLink' is a unique id do you should be safe to just match it directly by id or class without the previous tags. They are slowing you down.

Answer (score 1):

If ignoring that step is acceptable, then just ignore it -- remove the handling code, and let the next step's code take control naturally.